# Kafka cluster and Zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

suppose I have  3 Kafka server.
server1 zoopkeeper1 
server2 zoopkeeper2 
server3 zoopkeeper3 
In a cluster config what happens to the zoopkeepers ? are they maintained individually for each server or will their data sync up in cluster configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zookeepers need to be configured to form a cluster [1] and then they will indeed sync-up their data. Each kafka broker in a kafka cluster will be talking to the zookeeper cluster and this way the kafka cluster will function correctly.

On the other hand, if zookeepers haven't been configured for replication and each kafka broker talks to its individual zookeeper, then they will not constitute a healthy kafka cluster.

[1] https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.10/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_RunningReplicatedZooKeeper